# ionic svg filter error in android platform

Tags: android, ionic3, angular5, svg-filters

I'm using svg filter in div.

This code is perfectly worked when I test it on browser platform.

However, when I install it on android platform (using ionic cordova run android command), the app was directly crashed with no error message.

The html and css code is here.

```css
.circles {
    width: 60px;
    height: 19px;
    display: flex;
    //filter: url('#gooeyness');
    flex-direction: row;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
  }

  .circle,
  .circle-first,
  .circle-end{
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    //background: #A0D9F4;
    background: $text-content;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 75%;
    width: 17%;
    margin: 4.2% 5%;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    transition: border-color 700ms ease-in-out;
    transition: background-color 700ms ease-in-out;
  }

  .circle.active {
    border-color: white;
  }
```

```html
<svg class="filter" version="1.1">
    <defs>
      <filter id="gooeyness">
        <!--<feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3"/>-->
        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="4" result="blur" />
        <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 20 -10" result="gooey" />
        <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="gooey" operator="atop" />
      </filter>
    </defs>
  </svg>
  <div class="test-boxes">
    <div class="circles" style="filter: url('.#gooeyness');">
      <div class="circle-first" style="opacity: 0;"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="circle-end" style="opacity: 0;"></div>
      <div class="loader"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I found that the problem was because this filter was added.

> filter: url('#gooeyness')

It was no logical problem in my typescript code. So I tested other svg file and the same problem was occured.

Why does svg filter crash the ionic application on android platform?

Answer (score 0):

I can see at least one syntax error:

```
<feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" ...
```

should be

```
<feColorMatrix in="blur" type="matrix" ...
```

(only feBlend uses a mode attribute)

Comment: Thanks for the opinion, but the problem was not related to the point. When I commented 'feColorMatrix' line and tested the app, the app was crashed too.

Comment: Does it crash if you comment out both the feComposite & the feColorMatrix?

Comment: Yes, I commented all except feGaussianBlur and tested.

Comment: Then it's a straight up bug - sorry.